# AFNetworking 2 custom session manager

Tags: ios, json, serialization, afnetworking-2

I want to have session manager with base url instead of using the standard:

```
[AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
```

which IS 100% working, I've tested it, I'm trying with my own subclass.

So I've subclassed `AFHTTPSessionManager` and made shared instance:

```
+ (MySessionManager *)sharedModel {
    static MySessionManager *sharedInstance = nil;
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (sharedInstance == nil) {
            sharedInstance = [[self alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:kMyBaseURL]];
        }
    }

    return sharedInstance;
}

- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url {
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if (self) {
        // see description below
    }

    return self;
}
```

I've check the implementation of `AFHTTPSessionManager manager` and it looks like this:

```
+ (instancetype)manager {
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithBaseURL:nil];
}
```

So in fact my own subclass should work the same way.. but it doesn't!

I get status code `200` with `Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html`. However I'm sure it is json, because with `AFHTTPSessionManager manager` everything works fine and displays as text/json. What's the matter, what am I doing wrong?

--- edit ---

Also I've tried to set response/request serializers in `initWithBaseURL` but it didn't help.

```
self.requestSerializer = [AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer];
self.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
```

--- edit ---

I've also tried to user any configuration of these but everything failed (400, 401).

```
[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[self.requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[self.responseSerializer setAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", nil]];
```

Again: when using manager sharedInstance there is no problem at all - I'm in success block and can parse response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the whole problem was that kMyBaseURL was:

```
#define kMGBaseURL @"http://example.com/api"
```

instead of

```
#define kMGBaseURL @"http://example.com/api/"
```

and later I've used links as `@"/something"` instead of `@"something"`.